# IndexedDB writes fail on Chrome for Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, indexeddb

I'm confused about the state of IndexedDB support in Chrome for Android.

The [Todo list demo](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) from HTML5 Rocks works fine in Chrome 23 on my desktop. In Chrome 18 on Android 4.0.4, it looks promising: window.webkitIndexedDB exists, I can open a database and create a store. But as soon as I try to write to the store, I get a `READ_ONLY_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 9`.

Several overviews of Chrome for Android indicate that it supports IndexedDB, but I can't find any deeper discussions or documentation, or examples of people using it successfully.

Comment: Yes, confirm not working in Android 4. But interestingly Chrome beta for iOS 6 is working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

READ_ONLY_ERR: DOM IDBDatabase Exception 9

The error is saying what the problem is. You are trying to write data to the object store inside a readonly transaction. You need to open a transaction with readwrite.

```
db.transaction(["scope"], "readwrite");
```

**I'm not sure what version of indexeddb is implemented on android 4, so it's possible it still uses integer values. in that case you should use the following: window.webkitIDBTransaction.READ_WRITE if the webkit version is present or window.IDBTransaction.READ_WRITE if the native version is present.**

```
db.transaction(["scope"], window.webkitIDBTransaction.READ_WRITE);
```

**EDIT**
I looked at the source code of the project and seen that it uses the "readwrite" version allready. Maybe this isn't implmented yet in the android version? I would advise you to use the second possibility I gave you.

Comment: Yep, switching from "readwrite" to the READ_WRITE int constant did the trick. Thanks! Do you want to edit your answer to highlight the solution?

Comment: On closer review, this is just one of several things in the HTML5 Rocks demo that hasn't been updated to reflect changes in the API.

Comment: The HTML5 Rocks demo is the correct one, but in the previous implementation of the spec it was a constant instead of a string. The problem with the html5 rocks demo is that it isn't compatible with the older spec and so with older browser versions. If you want to learn some more about the indexeddb, try my blog http://www.kristofdegrave.be I have several post about the spec + I always try to give full compatible solutions